# how to run npm from nodeenv (virtual env)

Tags: node.js, npm, ansible, virtualenv

i have a ansible playbook which is installing nodeenv and then trying to run npm command. but npm command is not found.

here is the code

```
- name: install nodeenv
  pip:
    name: nodeenv
    umask: "0022"

- name: create venv
  command: nodeenv -v -n 6.14.4 --prebuilt - /opt/app/venv creates="/opt/app/venv"

- name: npm install
  command: npm install chdir="/opt/app/web"
  environment:
    NODE_VIRTUAL_ENV: "/opt/app/venv"
    PATH: "/opt/app/venv/lib/node_modules/.bin:/opt/app/venv/bin:/opt/app/web/node_modules/.bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
    NODE_PATH: "/opt/app/venv/lib/node_modules"
    NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX: "/opt/app/venv"
    npm_config_prefix: "/opt/app/venv"
```

also i want to know how do i run npm, commands inside the nodeenv

Comment: I guess you missed out on activating the env. Refer [nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv)

Comment: no. with ansible i have tried several things. but cannot activate the nodeenv. manually on the host i can invoke it.

Comment: I am sorry I can't help you with it because I don't have any knowledge of Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to manually configure all the environment variables, it may be easier to simply use the standard `activate` script to activate the nodeenv.  This will require using the `shell` module instead of the `command` module, like this:

```
- name: npm install
  shell: |
    . /opt/app/venv/bin/activate
    npm install
  args:
    chdir: /opt/app/web
```